# I'm trying to sort a PHP Array, but can't figure out how

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, grouping, multidimensional-array

How do you convert an array in PHP that looks like this:

```
Array ( 
      [2] => B.eot
      [3] => B.ttf
      [4] => CarnevaleeFreakshow.ttf
      [5] => CarnevaleeFreakshow.eot
      [6] => TRASHED.ttf
      [7] => sub.ttf
      )
```

To look like this:

```
Array(
     [B]=>array(
               [0] => B.eot
               [1] => B.ttf
               )
     [CarnevaleeFreakshow]=>array(
               [0] => CarnevaleeFreakshow.ttf
               [1] => CarnevaleeFreakshow.eot
               )
     [TRASHED]=>array(
               [0] => TRASHED.ttf
               )
     [sub]=>array(
               [0] => sub.ttf
               )
     )
```

Is there a name for doing something like this?
the data is being retrieved from a

```
 scandir
```

array.

Comment: you are not *sorting*, you are *grouping* (and then perhaps sorting the groups, though your example fails to demonstrate this)

Comment: where are you getting the data for your array?

Comment: use multi-dimensional array..

Comment: It's the result of a `scandir`, only `files` are being returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$data = array ( 
  2 => 'B.eot',
  3 => 'B.ttf',
  4 => 'CarnevaleeFreakshow.ttf',
  5 => 'CarnevaleeFreakshow.eot',
  6 => 'TRASHED.ttf',
  7 => 'sub.ttf'
 ); 

$new_data = array();
foreach ( $data as $value ) {
    $tmp = explode( '.', $value );
    $ext = '';
    if ( $tmp[1] ) $ext = '.' . $tmp[1];
    $new_data[ $tmp[0] ][] = $tmp[0] . $ext;
}

print_r( $new_data );

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example.

It can be written shorter, but I think this is the most instructive.

```
$ARRraw = array (
      "B.eot",
      "B.ttf",
      "CarnevaleeFreakshow.ttf",
      "CarnevaleeFreakshow.eot",
      "TRASHED.ttf",
      "sub.ttf"
      ) ;


$sorted = array();
foreach($ARRraw as $one){
  $firstPoint = strpos($one,".");
  // No point? then skip.
  if (!($firstPoint === false)){
    // Get the part before the point.
    $myKey = substr($one,0,$firstPoint);
    $sorted[$myKey][] = $one;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a name for doing something like this?

Nope. Anyway, it should be rather simple using a loop:

```
<?php
$newArray = array( );

foreach( $originalArray as $fontfile ) {
    $newArray[basename( $font )][] = $fontfile;
}
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $newArray, true );
```

Answer (score 0):

To what i know there is no 'simple' method of doing this.
you could build a function to handle it though.

```
function convertArray($array) {
    $newArray = array();

    foreach( $array as $item ) {
        $newArray[basename($item)] = $item;
    }

    return $newArray;
}
```

That should do what your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
function subdiv(array $arr) {
$res = array();
foreach($arr as $val) {
    $tmp = explode('.', $val);
    if(!isset($res[$tmp[0]]))
        $res[$tmp[0]] = array();
    $res[$tmp[0]][] = $val;
} return $res;
}
```

use with:

```
$res = subdiv($array);
var_dump($res);
```